# How to determine haproxy number of connections per process?

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

I am new in haproxy. Want to determine what is the number of connection in my haproxy?
I attached an image.
In haproxy server how can I see number of concurrent connection?
[haproxy stats image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccqNm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Existing connections are conn-current connections.

You can use the stats socket to get that data.

```
# echo "show info" | socat stdio /etc/path-to-socket/stats
Name: HAProxy
Version: 2.x.x
CurrConns: 100
CumConns: 105
```